# Python C Extension: check if module attributes are read-only using introspection

Tags: python, python-c-api, inspect

I am currently trying to write a Python extension module using the Python C API.
In some of my objects, I am defining read-only attributes using `PyGetSetDef` descriptors which look as follows:

```
PyGetSetDef get_set_descriptors[] = {
    {
        (char*) "foo",
        (getter) get_foo,
        (setter) 0,
        (char*) "Docstring",
        NULL
    },
    { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL }  // sentinel
};
```

Now, I am trying to generate a documentation file for my extension module. For this purpose, I am using the `inspect` module in a Python script to iterate over all classes, methods, and attributes for each class in the module.

When looking at the `Object` instance corresponding to my get-set descriptor, I find members for both `__set__` and `__get__` - without any way to differentiate whether the corresponding properties are meant to be read-only (or write-only, FWIW) or not.

Is there a way to programmatically check whether class attributes defined in Python extension modules are read-only using introspection?